# Does a global phpunit check for local version?

Tags: phpunit

I have installed phpunit globally (v7.1.4). My project uses phpunit `^6` as defined in `composer.json`.

If I run `$ phpunit --version` within the project dir I see:

```
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 7.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

But if I run my tests another version is used:

```
$ phpunit
PHPUnit 6.5.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.............                                                     13 / 13 (100%)

Time: 839 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

OK (13 tests, 16 assertions)
```

My question is: Does phpunit check for a locally installed version and uses this for the project or is my system acting weired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PHPUnit does nothing of the sort.

You have a project-local version of PHPUnit installed via Composer but do not invoke it via `./vendor/bin/phpunit`. Thus the globally installed PHPUnit is used.